# unable to find listener during webservices load (tomcat) gradle build fails

Tags: web-services, tomcat, jakarta-ee, gradle

Tomcat is unable to find my listener when I build using gradle

> 13-Dec-2016 20:38:22.753 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>com.my.webservice.utilities.WebService</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The listener is available in `WEB-INF/classes/com/my/webservice/utilities/WebService.class`

Part of my gradle file is

```
dependencies {
    compile files('src') ;
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

war {
    webXml = file('WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml') // copies a file to WEB-INF/web.xml
}
```

**Edit**

In the localhost.2016-12-13.log I got this

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class com.my.webservice.utilities.WebService java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.webservice.utilities.WebService

Comment: The error says that the filter failed to start - are you sure that it wasn't found or was there another error?  Take a look at the logs for more details.

Comment: in the localhost.2016-12-13.log I got this `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring application listener of class com.my.webservice.utilities.WebService
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.webservice.utilities.WebService`